# Xcode 6.0.1 out of control with 100% CPU usage

Tags: xcode6, cpu

I upgrade my xcode to Version 6.1 (6A1052d), open any project will run up the CPU to 100% 
[image]

Comment: This would be more suited for http://superuser.com/ peeps

Comment: It might be reindexing. Have you tried just letting it finish?

Comment: after reindex done, it still out of control, reinstall the xcode cannot resolve this issue